# ActionScript fisheye effect

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm looking to make a fisheye effect on a textfield for a project. I've already found some code on the internet but it doesn't quite render how i'd like for it to (the text is pixelated and deformed, I want a nice round fisheye). Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post code / screenshot of what you've done and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Agree w/@matt... but you can certainly achieve an effect like this wth pixel bender and as3 shader class.

Answer (score 0):

First in the text properties select "anti-alias" for animation.

If the text isn't generated dynamically or need to be changed then select it and go to Modify => Break apart in the top menu and then repeat to transform it into a vector.